# C#: O(n²) solution to finding n/k elements of an array of of size n and a number k

Tags: c#, arrays

[Link where I got the problem from](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/given-an-array-of-of-size-n-finds-all-the-elements-that-appear-more-than-nk-times/)

I'm trying for a O(n²) solution to finding which elements appear **more** than n/k times (where n=8 in this case - so more than twice) in the given array. I believe I have the solution but I can't seem to figure out why the output (shown below) isn't [2, 3]. I know that it's element 2 at index i = 3 that appears but I figured the `if (count > (arr.Length / k))` condition would've fixed that.

```
int[] arr = { 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3 };
int k = 4, count = 1;

for(int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
    for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.Length; j++)
    {
        if (arr[i] == arr[j])
        {
            count++;
            if (count > (arr.Length / k))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(arr[i] + " " + i);
                count = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
3 0

2 2

2 3
```

Comment: You're not resetting `count` in the right place.  It should reset after the inner `for` loop, not inside of your `if` statements.

Comment: As an optimisation, consider calculating `arr.Length / k` only once (i.e. assign to a variable outside of the loops). Also, consider what you want to occur if `arr.Length` was 9 and `k` was `4`. What result would you expect `arr.Length / k` to return (and is that what you get)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're only resetting the `count` when there's a match and the `count` is greater than `arr.Length/k`.  You need to reset it at the end of the inner `for` loop or better yet define it just before the inner `for` loop since it isn't needed outside of that loop.  Also I'm guessing you'll want to break from that loop as soon as the `count` meets your condition or you'll keep writing out the same thing.

```
int[] arr = { 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3 };
int k = 4;

for(int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
    int count = 1;
    for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.Length; j++)
    {
        if (arr[i] == arr[j])
        {
            count++;
            if (count > (arr.Length / k))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(arr[i] + " " + i );
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However this will still produce results for duplicate values at other locations.  For instance the array {3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3} with k equal to 4 produces 3,0; 3,6; 3,7; and 3,8.  Assuming you only want 3,0 then a better solution would be.

```
int[] arr = { 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3 };
int k = 4;    

var results = arr.Select((x,i) => new {Value = x, Index = i})
    .GroupBy(x => x.Value)
    .Where(grp => grp.Count() > arr.Length / k)
    .Select(grp => grp.First());

foreach(var r in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{r.Value} {r.Index}");
}
```

Or if you prefer to stick with `for` loops instead of Linq then all you need is a `HashSet<int>` to keep track of the values you've already seen.

```
int[] arr = { 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3 };
int k = 4;
HashSet<int> seen  = new HashSet<int>();

for(int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
    if(!seen.Add(arr[i]))
    {
        continue;
    }

    int count = 1;
    for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.Length; j++)
    {
        if (arr[i] == arr[j])
        {
            count++;
            if (count > (arr.Length / k))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(arr[i] + " " + i );
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that `Add` returns false when the value is already in the hash set.

Answer (score 0):

Would this not be the most optimised way? Because you don't want to check the last `arr.Length/k` elements because if all were the same then they would only be `are.Length/k` and not `> are.Length/k` in Quantity

```
int[] arr = { 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3 };
int k = 4;
int target = arr.Length/k;
for(int i = 0; i < arr.Length - target; i++)
{
    int count = 1;
    for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.Length; j++)
   {
        if (arr[i] == arr[j])
       {
           count++;
           if (count > (target))
           {
               Console.WriteLine(arr[i] + " " + i );
               break;
           }
       }
   }
}
```

If you could use an algorithm to sort of `O(n log n)` or less then something like this may be useful:

```
int[] arr = { 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3 };
int[] sorted = Sort(arr); //sort method
int k = 4;
int target = arr.Length/k;
int count = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < arr.Length - target; i++)
{
     count++;
     if(arr[i] != arr[i+1])
     { 
        if(count > target)
           Console.WriteLine($"{arr[i]} {count}");
        count = 0;
     }
}
```